# how could I can I read an array I save in a cookie with jquery.cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I am using jquery.cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1) and Ive been having many problems with this, I am trying to save an array of this structure

```
var obj = {
    'row1' : {
        'key1' : 'input1',
        'key2' : 'inpu2'
    },
    'row2' : {
        'key3' : 'input3',
        'key4' : 'input4'
    }
};
```

But when I want to read it I get this

```
row1%5Bkey1%5D=input1&row1%5Bkey2%5D=inpu2&row2%5Bkey3%5D=input3&row2%5Bkey4%5D=input4
```

I am sending it at this way:

```
$.cookie('listresult', $.param(obj), { expires: 10 });
```

The worst is that sometimes works, and sometimes doesnt, so, I have no idea whats wrong... Any idea how to send and transform the data?

To read it I use this

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("listresult");
```

When I try this... doesnt work

```
$.parseJSON($.cookie("listresult");)
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `$.param()` for this.  That escapes characters that are special in a URL.  You probably want to serialize to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how should I send it then?

Comment: The two answers below show you two ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `jquery.param` method. It is intended for use with HTTP (AJAX) requests so that's not your case. You have to use `JSON.stringify` on writing cookie and `JSON.parse` on reading:

```
// write (save):
$.cookie('listresult', JSON.stringify(obj), { expires: 10 });

// read (restore):
var obj = JSON.parse($.cookie('listresult'));
```

Comment: If you read my previous answer, this plugin supports what you've suggested out-of-the-box......

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully read jQuery plugin's manual, you'll find this:

> json
>
> Turn on automatic storage of JSON objects passed as the cookie value.
>   Assumes JSON.stringify and JSON.parse:
>
> $.cookie.json = true;

This way your JavaScript objects will be serialized to JSON when you set the whole cookie, and they'll get deserialized into a JavaScript again when you retrieve that cookie.

Comment: I tried that, but I dont know where to put it, when I save it or when I read it? (I tried just before save)

Comment: @jpganz18 I guess you should create a file called something like `init.js` which might be added to your HTML source after jQuery, so every plugin is already initialized with settings when you're going to use it in actual code.